# Function to choose greatest value based on an ID value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've put in a function that concatenated some values, but I want them to show just the greatest values per ID.

They always follow that pattern, but sometimes there is only one value per ID and sometimes there is no value.

```
╔═══╦═════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║   ║  a  ║       b       ║       c       ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1 ║ ID  ║ LIST VALUES   ║ RESULT NEEDED ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2 ║ 123 ║ 111           ║ 111, 222      ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 3 ║ 123 ║ 111, 222      ║ 111, 222      ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 4 ║ 456 ║ 444           ║ 444, 777, 999 ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 5 ║ 456 ║ 444, 777      ║ 444, 777, 999 ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 6 ║ 456 ║ 444, 777, 999 ║ 444, 777, 999 ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 7 ║ 789 ║ 221           ║ 221           ║
╚═══╩═════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Here is a sample table, with Col C being the values I need.

I've tried this function for Col C (for C7):

```
=IF(A7=A6, IF(ISBLANK(B7)=FALSE, IF(B7>=B6, B7, C8), "BLANK ERR"), B7)
```

That failed. All of my values are similar, but weird.

It's hard for my brain to wrap around it. Any solutions?

edit:C7 was wrong!

Comment: why is C7 `888`?

Comment: oops! that should be 221, I'll fix it now

Comment: Are the list value always compounding and as sorted like you have it?

Comment: yes, they always increase until it changes IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is sorted as you described, then try in `C2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,TRUE)
```

Or use an `INDEX` and `MATCH` combo:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,A:A))
```

If data is unsorted you could use `LOOKUP`, in `C2`:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A$7=A2),B$2:B$7)
```

---

[image]

Comment: That would return `111` in C2 and C3, would it not?

Comment: Not on my end @ScottCraner. Let me send a screenshot with this for reference.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The assumption is that the ID are in ascending order.

Comment: yes, it's sorted that way, but on a larger set of data, it returns other values from other IDs

Comment: If the sample data is not representing what your data actually looks like, please adjust in your original question for others to see. Meanwhile try the `LOOKUP` version @hanbanan

Comment: the lookup worked best. i think the vlookup with the search not based on an exact match was messing up the results. the data i have is much larger than that table.